# Laravel Sanctum master key on multi tenant API

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-sanctum, laravel-lighthouse

i'm trying to build a multi tenant API and so far my APIs are working great and i managed to implement multi-tenancy ( using [archtechx/tenancy](https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy) ), authentication with sanctum issuing keys is also working fine.

The application is structured such as there is a central domain `example.com`, the users that have access to this domain are called "Superadmins", they should be able to access with their API token (issued by sanctum on login) every other subdomain (or tenant) APIs with unrestricted access.

The tenants are on subdomains such as `tenant.example.com` and have personal databases, one for each tenant.

I was thinking about a couple of solutions to implement this:

1. let the Superadmin Impersonate an admin of the tenant API and do stuff as that admin
2. find a way to issue "Master keys" to superadmins that work on every tenant (subdomain)

I would lean towards the second solution because i find it more elegant. I've been searching the web for best practices for this kind of problem/feature but i haven't found anything that matches my question exactly.

In conclusion, is solution number 2 workable? And if so, is there a way to issue such "Master keys" with sanctum?

I'm using:

Laravel 8.48.1

[Lighthouse-php](https://lighthouse-php-com/) as a framework to serve GraphQL through Laravel

Sanctum as Authentication guard

[Tenancy for Laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) as a Multi-tenancy package

Comment: I am currently using this package in three different projects with multiple tenants in each project. It would be interesting to know the solution to this need. Both of the ways you propose seem reasonable, however it would be necessary to investigate which one is the best, or if there are better ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Master keys**

A simple thought: you could set [token abilities](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#token-abilities) for Sanctum tokens. Perhaps you could create the ability of `master:access` or something similar, that function as a `Master key`? You could grant super admins the `master:access` ability while creating the API token for them.

This does require the `tenant` to access the `master` DB and authorize the ability of that specific key. I do not know the specific implementation of that package, but the Tenancy projects I worked with before provided easy access to the `master` DB. You could implement some kind of middleware or authorization to check if the user has a token with the `master:access` ability.

**Impersonating users**

Your other proposed solution of impersonating, also seems possible and is offered by the package according to the [package documentation](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/features/user-impersonation). This does require every tenant to have some kind of `admin` user. Since all `Superadmins` have access to the tenant over 1 shared `admin` user, I would not advise to go for this option.

Comment: That's a good idea, the only "issue" I find in it is that I would have to check if an user is a super admin for each API call I make on a tenant API.
I was thinking about creating an user on each tenant upon tenant creation with no password so you can't login to it from a tenant. When a superadmin logs in I would issue a key and store it as a key for that dummy user that is actually a superadmin.
Do you think this can be a feasible solution?

Comment: I understand! But you would have to check anyway if the token is valid; you could combine in that call the check if the user is actually a super admin? Regarding your question, do you have multiple superadmins, and are you creating a dummy user for each superadmin? If you are, that seems like massive overhead. If you are creating only one user, I think it would work, but consider if you need access to a specific user on the Tenant. For example, if you would like to log actions of a specific Superadmin, how would you distinguish one from the other?

Comment: Yeah I see, you are right. I think a middleware would be the best approach to it. The only problem is that i would authenticate the SuperAdmin "By hand" in this case and i should be able to skip the sanctum authentication middleware to avoid conflicts i guess. Or i can swap to main DB before sanctum auth and then swap back to the current tenant DB.

Comment: You would indeed have to authenticate the SuperAdmin by hand, creating your own kind of `Middleware`. But this could be as `simple` as making an API call that returns a boolean whether the user is authorized or not. How do you currently check the validity of an `API token`? It seems to me this would have to happen anyway, since the Personal Access Tokens are centrally stored on your `Master` database, there needs to be some kind of connection to the central DB. Switching `DB connections` run time seems possible as well, but I don't know if this integrates well with the `Sanctum` middleware.

Comment: The middleware stack used by `Lighthouse` on any incoming request is:
`\App\Http\Middleware\InitializeGqlTenanctByDomain::class`
This initialize the DB and Logs to the tenant that made the request
`\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class`
This is the Sanctum stateful requests Middleware
`\Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Http\Middleware\AttemptAuthentication::class`
And this is the `Lighthouse` built in middleware to handle authentication down to the field level (GraphQL) and it uses Sanctum as Auth Guard. 
------ Part 1 ------

Comment: In this case i should apply a middleware and swap DB before the last middleware and swap back after it, or i could skip it altogether since i wouldn't need Field level authentication since a SuperAdmin can access everything anyway
----- Part 2 -----

Comment: I guess you skip swapping back indeed, since a SuperAdmin can access everything... sounds like switching connections run time might be your best way to go then!